# Angular: Single service in multiple files

Tags: angularjs

I have a singleton that creates classes for me. Each class is in a separate file.

```
// singleton.js

angular.module('mymodule')
  .service('singleton', SingletonClass)

// someclass1.js, someclass2.js, ...
// Multiple files with same layout. Each web page has different # of these files.
// Therefore, it's hard to inject them statically
// (ie, via aggregator service/factory).

angular.module('mymodule')
  .??('someClass', function(singleton) {
    classOptions = {}; // details here
    // creates a class with options and adds it to `singleton`s cache
    singleton.addClass(classOptions);

  })

// yet another file

angular.module('mymodule')
  .controller('myController', function(singleton) {
    singleton.getClasses(); // gets all classes added by #addClass method
  });
```

Basically, I want each individual "class" to be self-contained in its own file similar to how modules are self-contained. That means I don't want want `singleton` or any aggregator service/factory to know of the existence of these classes in its creation.

**Edit:**

I'd like to clarify: I'm using `singleton` instead of individually injecting the created classes because **I don't yet know which classes will be created yet**. The web page will dynamically load certain js files. Each file will inject the singleton object and use the `addClass` method to create a new class and store it inside the `singleton` object itself. The controllers using `singleton.getClasses()` won't know how many or which classes it's getting, but they have a uniform interface which allows it to use them in a predictable fashion.

Comment: How about `angular.module('mymodule').factory`? That basically makes your classes into services, which may not be what you want. Incidentally, services _are_ singletons, so . . . do you really need singleton classes?

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want to use `singleton` then stop using it. If you want dependency injection then use it: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di What is the actual question?

Comment: @tandrewnichols I don't need a factory in this case. `singleton` has a method `#addClass` that I want to access. It takes classOptions (an object) and transforms them into a class with certain characteristics. It also stores this newly created class for controllers to use.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I do want to use singleton. It's very useful. The problem is how to extend it in multiple files. I am showing my use of it in 'yet another file'. The reason I'm using #getClasses instead of dependency injection in this case is because the code that uses these newly made classes **has no way of knowing what classes exist**. It's dynamic so I can't require them statically.

Comment: This comment makes it clear why you're doing it: "The reason I'm using #getClasses instead of dependency injection in this case is because the code that uses these newly made classes has no way of knowing what classes exist. It's dynamic so I can't require them statically." Thanks. But my suggestion still stands. Use `.factory` for each class. Inject `singleton`. Call `singleton.addClass` with whatever options. I was just replacing your `??` with what seems like the most likely method to call.

Comment: Got it. You don't know how to get `singleton.addClass` to be called for each of them without actually injecting them as a dependency somewhere. And you can't simply list them as dependencies to the singleton because not all of them might be defined. You need to use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector - specifically the `has` and `instantiate` methods it exposes.

Comment: @tandrewnichols Hm, I was doing some testing on this but it didn't give the expected result. My biggest question mark is this: Declaring the factory recipe itself doesn't call it. Angular requires these factory recipes be called via dependency injecting somewhere; this would require knowledge of which class files were added to the page.

Comment: Interesting. I did not realize that, but you're correct. So it must be doing just-in-time initialization. You could try using providers: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-receipe. I'll post another idea in an answer too (don't think it will fit here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting up providers for each class (per my comment above), though that seems . . . time consuming. Maybe you just don't need it? Make each class a separate file in a closure (like you use to need to do with jquery), and grab the singleton object from the injector:

```
// file 1 - Add other files for other classes.
;(function(window, $) {
  $(function() {
    var classOptions = {};
    $('body').injector().get('singleton').addClass(classOptions);
  });
})(window, jQuery);
```

This is not exactly the angular way, and angular purists will call for your head, but I think it will achieve what you're after if you don't want to mess with providers.

Comment: I've only tested your injector method, but that and provider recipes seem like the both workable solutions. Thanks!